# Git changelog: how to get all changes up to a specific tag?

Tags: git, logging, changelog

Is there an easy way or command to get all git commits up to a specific tag to generate an automatic changelog for a project? I always tag my git repos with a version number like `v0.1.0` and for instance would like all commits up to tag `v0.1.0`.

I've looked through the docs but don't seem to find a useful option or command for it: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log (is down at the moment by the way)

For instance:

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate
```

Shows the tags next to commits. I'd like the same, but only up to specific tag.

Comment: Relevant to your interests: Pimp My Changelog, a Ruby script to do this. https://github.com/pcreux/pimpmychangelog

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can just do:

```
git log --oneline --decorate v0.1.0
```

... to show every commit up to and including v0.1.0.  Of course, `git log` allows also allows you to restrict the commits shown in any of the ways that `git rev-list` understands, so if you only wanted to see the changes between `v0.0.9` and `v0.1.0` you could also do:

```
git log --oneline --decorate v0.0.9..v0.1.0
```

Alternative output that might be useful for this purpose is that of `git shortlog`, which groups and summarizes the contributions of each author.  Try, for example:

```
git shortlog v0.1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer :) This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: To display commits after a specific tag you can use `git log --oneline --decorate v0.1.0..`

Comment: How to copy the log after running the git command i.e. git log --oneline --decorate ?

Comment: How to save it in a file?

Comment: @MateusViccari You would use output redirection with `>`, e.g. `git log --oneline --decorate v0.0.9..v0.1.0 > changes.txt`

Answer (score 8):

For creating changelog by tags, i used this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Author:Andrey Nikishaev
echo "CHANGELOG"
echo ----------------------
git tag -l | sort -u -r | while read TAG ; do
    echo
    if [ $NEXT ];then
        echo [$NEXT]
    else
        echo "[Current]"
    fi
    GIT_PAGER=cat git log --no-merges --format=" * %s" $TAG..$NEXT
    NEXT=$TAG
done
FIRST=$(git tag -l | head -1)
echo
echo [$FIRST]
GIT_PAGER=cat git log --no-merges --format=" * %s" $FIRST
```

Comment: If your tags are versions on the form x.y.z, add the `-V` flag to `sort` to correctly sort versions like 1.0.9, 1.0.10, etc.

Answer (score 4):

There is a very useful gem, the output is written in markdown, add issue support and split commits by tags

https://github.com/kebab-project/katip

Answer (score 3):

Just use the tag name as a commit specifier: `git log --oneline --decorate v0.1.0`

Answer (score 3):

An update to the script suggested by Creotiv to get better sorting of the tags

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Author:Andrey Nikishaev, Gunnar Lindholm
echo "CHANGELOG"
echo ----------------------
git for-each-ref --sort='*authordate' --format='%(tag)' refs/tags |tac |grep -v '^$' | while read TAG ; do
     echo
    if [ $NEXT ];then
        echo [$NEXT]
    else
        echo "[Current]"
    fi
    GIT_PAGER=cat git log --no-merges --format=" * %s" $TAG..$NEXT
    NEXT=$TAG
done
FIRST=$(git tag -l | head -1)
echo
echo [$FIRST]
GIT_PAGER=cat git log --no-merges --format=" * %s" $FIRST
```

Answer (score 3):

I came up with this modification of the original script. This handles version tags correctly.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Author:Andrey Nikishaev
echo "CHANGELOG"
echo ----------------------
git tag -l --sort=v:refname | tac | while read TAG ; do
    echo
    if [ $NEXT ];then
        echo [$NEXT]
    else
        echo "[Current]"
    fi
    GIT_PAGER=cat git log --no-merges --format=" * %s" $TAG..$NEXT
    NEXT=$TAG
done
FIRST=$(git tag -l --sort=v:refname | head -1)
echo
echo [$FIRST]
GIT_PAGER=cat git log --no-merges --format=" * %s" $FIRST
```

Answer (score 2):

Just append *`tagname`* to your command and you should be fine :) I like the `--graph` switch to visualize the branches that led to that tag :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Git Changelog Command Line](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-changelog-command-line) to do this:

```
npx git-changelog-command-line -std -tr v0.1.0 -tec "
# Changelog

Changelog for {{ownerName}} {{repoName}}.

{{#tags}}
## {{name}}
 {{#issues}}
  {{#hasIssue}}
   {{#hasLink}}
### {{name}} [{{issue}}]({{link}}) {{title}} {{#hasIssueType}} *{{issueType}}* {{/hasIssueType}} {{#hasLabels}} {{#labels}} *{{.}}* {{/labels}} {{/hasLabels}}
   {{/hasLink}}
   {{^hasLink}}
### {{name}} {{issue}} {{title}} {{#hasIssueType}} *{{issueType}}* {{/hasIssueType}} {{#hasLabels}} {{#labels}} *{{.}}* {{/labels}} {{/hasLabels}}
   {{/hasLink}}
  {{/hasIssue}}
  {{^hasIssue}}
### {{name}}
  {{/hasIssue}}

  {{#commits}}
**{{{messageTitle}}}**

{{#messageBodyItems}}
 * {{.}} 
{{/messageBodyItems}}

[{{hash}}](https://github.com/{{ownerName}}/{{repoName}}/commit/{{hash}}) {{authorName}} *{{commitTime}}*

  {{/commits}}

 {{/issues}}
{{/tags}}
"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using https://pypi.org/project/changelogfromtags/

```sh
pip install changelogfromtags && changelogfromtags
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this command for one specified tag

**git for-each-ref --format '%(contents)' refs/tags/v0.1.0**

change **v.0.1.0** with desired tag