# Git and changelog guideline

Tags: git, markdown, bitbucket, changelog

I'm a *noob* with git and i would like to know the best practice to create tags and generate/mantain a changelog.

Until now, i always created a readme.md and manually indicate (in the section "changelog") the most important feature

For example:

> version 1.0.1
>
> - changed layout in home
> - added slideshow in gallery
> - etc..

How can i create a changelog (maybe in markdown format) with these characteristics?

- title of changes based on personalized title/tags title/date
- changes based on tags or commits

I do not have a clear idea yet, so suggestions are aprreciate

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you looked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387612/git-changelog-how-to-get-all-changes-up-to-a-specific-tag)?

Comment: +1 @Mali in the age of VCSs, inserting a changelog into a repository is anachronistic, just like inserting the date as a source file comment. Separate data from metadata!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are no some common guidelines yet. But a lot of good rules are explained on **[keep a changelog](http://keepachangelog.com)**.

And as they mention:

> Don’t let your friends dump git logs into changelogs.

And I fully agree with it.

That's why I created [GitHub Changelog Generator](https://github.com/skywinder/github-changelog-generator) that generates a changelog according all these guidelines.

Actually it works with **GitHub only**, but it present a good example of how a changelog should look like.

It automatically generates a changelog from your tags, issues, labels and pull requests.

For example: This changelog was generated by this script: **[CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)**

> ## Changelog
>
> ### [1.2.5](https://github.com/skywinder/github-changelog-generator/tree/1.2.5) (2015-01-15)
>
> [Full Changelog](https://github.com/skywinder/github-changelog-generator/compare/1.2.4...1.2.5)
>
> **Implemented enhancements:**
>
> - Use milestone to specify in which version bug was fixed [#22](https://github.com/skywinder/github-changelog-generator/issues/22)
>
> **Fixed bugs:**
>
> - Error when trying to generate log for repo without tags [#32](https://github.com/skywinder/github-changelog-generator/issues/32)
>
> **Merged pull requests:**
>
> - PrettyPrint class is included using lowercase 'pp' [#43](https://github.com/skywinder/github-changelog-generator/pull/43) ([schwing](https://github.com/schwing))
> - support enterprise github via command line options [#42](https://github.com/skywinder/github-changelog-generator/pull/42) ([glenlovett](https://github.com/glenlovett))

Comment: Does that mean every time we do a commit, we'll have to submit another commit to save the CHANGELOG.md in the repo after every commit?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you still manually describe the changes in the changelog.

Though, you can link to a generated changes via github diff.
For example, the changelog:
https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/Changelog.md

And the diff:
https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/compare/v2.14.2...master

You may want to look around in the repositories of some other reference opensource projects where a lot of good practices can be found.

Answer (score 3):

Probably my Asnwer is too late, but now I'm using a amazing ruby gem, it read your git log and split by tags, and the output is written in markdown, take a look

https://github.com/kebab-project/katip