# Github: How to search in all Release notes of a repository?

Tags: github, search, release, issue-tracking

I want to search all release notes (including all past release notes) of [Pandoc Repository, Github](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/2.5), for search term: `#4817`. How can I do it?

Comment: it looks like the feature is not implemented yet...

Comment: Suggestion: use the REST API to download a list of all releases, then iterate through them and use a regular expression on the `body` element of the JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from the #nnnn format that you are looking for a PR or an Issue.
One can look-up [Issue #4817](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4817) by using Github API directly:

https://github.com/search?q=4817+repo:jgm/pandoc+is:issue

Note that '#' had to be omitted.

To look among commits, *git* command that extract for later search the entire log for the repo has [been described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387612/git-changelog-how-to-get-all-changes-up-to-a-specific-tag) earlier:

```
git log --oneline --decorate
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this useful CLI [github-release-search](https://github.com/KittyGiraudel/github-release-search)
Basically it does what Tom Morris was suggesting above.

1. Fetch and cache releases
2. Search releases (note that you have to escape the `#` as such: `\#4817`